# What are the units used for each variable in the general formula for drude conductivity?

Tags: electromagnetism

The general formula for the Drude conductivity is confusing me. I was wondering if someone could point out the units which are normally used of each variable in the following equation for drude conductivity:

\begin{align}
\frac{n e^2 \tau}{m} = \sigma
\end{align}

Thanks in advance.
Note:
$\tau =$ elastic scattering time
$n =$ density of electrons

Comment: Mark this with a homework-and-exercises tag.

Comment: You literally asked this same question in the linked/closed question above

Answer (score 1):

In SI units,

- $n$ is the number density (number of charges per unit volume), which
  has units of $\text{m}^{-3}$,
- $e$ is the electron charge, which has units of $\text{C}$,
- $\tau$ is the collision time, with units of $\text{s}$,
- $m$ is the electron mass, with units of $\text{kg}$.

Putting it all together, the Drude conductivity has units
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{C}^2\cdot \text{s}}{\text{kg}\cdot \text{m}^3} = \frac{\text{A}^2\cdot \text{s}^3}{\text{kg}\cdot \text{m}^3},
\end{align}
as we'd expect for a conductivity.